# Clarifying expectation with respect to a function, and the Radon-Nikodym derivative

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, information-theory, radon-nikodym

I am trying to understand induced measures in the context of expectation. I have commonly seen formulas such as KL-divergence written like so:

$$\text{KL}(p||q) = \int\log\dfrac{p(x)}{q(x)}dp = \int p(x) \log\dfrac{p(x)}{q(x)}dx = \mathbb{E}_{p(x)}[\log\dfrac{p(x)}{q(x)}]$$

which reads as the expectation of the formula $\log\dfrac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ with respect to the measure $p(x)$. But over what set is this measure being taken?

Is it over the entire real line: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x) \log\dfrac{p(x)}{q(x)}dx$?

Or is it over the support of $p$: $\int_{x:p(x) >0} p(x) \log\dfrac{p(x)}{q(x)}dx$?

For the KL-divergence formula these turn out to be the same, but consider the expectation $\mathbb{E}_{p(x)}[\dfrac{q(x)}{p(x)}] = \int p(x)\dfrac{q(x)}{p(x)}dx = \int q(x)dx$.

In the case of the real line, we have $\int_{-\infty}^\infty q(x)dx = 1$.

In the case of the support of $p$, we have $\int_{x:p(x)>0} q(x)dx$, which is obviously very different.

I believe the second is correct, but I was unable to prove this in a way that satisfied me intellectually. My work is as follows:

Interpreting $p$ as the Radon-Nikodym derivative of an induced measure $\nu$, and letting $S$ represent the support $S = \{x: p(x) > 0\}$, we can calculate $\int \log\dfrac{q(x)}{p(x)}dp = \int_S \dfrac{q(x)}{p(x)}dp + \int_{S^C} \dfrac{q(x)}{p(x)}dp$. We have $\nu(S^C) = \int_{S^C} p(x)dx  = 0$, thus the second integral $\int_{S^C} \dfrac{q(x)}{p(x)}dp = 0$ and that leaves us with the integral over the support as desired.

To me, this proof seems valid but it also seems like cheating. I just basically look at the set of measure $0$ and declare that I can ignore it even though the value being integrated over there ($\dfrac{q(x)}{p(x)}$) is infinite. [This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326185/interpretation-of-radon-nikodym-derivative-between-probability-measures) on a similar question stated I could do that, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Some typos in the "Interpreting $p$ as the..." paragraph (first integral should be $\int  \frac{q(x)}{p(x)} \, dp$?)

Comment: yeah, just fixed! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

- $E_{X \sim p} \log \frac{p(X)}{q(X)}$ is actually shorthand for $E_{X \sim p} f(X)$ where $f(x) = \begin{cases} \log \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} & p(x) > 0 \\ 0 & p(x) = 0\end{cases}$. The assumption of absolute continuity ($q(x)=0$ implies $p(x)=0$) ensures that $f$ is well-defined (no division by zero). This needs to be explicitly baked into the definition of the KL divergence, since "$\log \frac{0}{0}$" and "$0 \log \frac{0}{0}$" are ambiguous.
- Similarly, if you write $E_{X \sim p} \frac{q(X)}{p(X)}$, you need to be explicit in how you define the function. You could say $E_{X \sim p} g(X)$ where $g(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{q(x)}{p(x)} & p(x) > 0 \\ 0 & p(x) = 0\end{cases}$ if you wish, but this is something that needs to be stated; $E_{X \sim p} \frac{q(X)}{p(X)}$ alone is ambiguous, since you get a $0 \cdot \infty$ situation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware of the absolute continuity requirement for KL, but I was assuming $f(x)$ did not have to explicitly be $0$ when $p(x) = 0$, since $x \log \dfrac{x}{c} \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ by L'hopitals. Edit: just checked Wikipedia, they also state this

Comment: So what I am reading is that usages of $\mathbb{E}_{X \sim p}[*]$ notation are non-rigorous?

Comment: @EricHe Not at all. $\mathbb{E}_P[f(X)] = \int f(X) \mathrm{d}P$ unambiguously. What angryavian is pointing out is that you're not defining $f$ clearly - when I set $f(x) = \frac{q(x)}{p(x)},$ what is $f$ when $p(x) = 0$? If you say $\infty,$ then why is $\infty \cdot 0 = q(x)$?

Comment: However, your actual question is dealt with rather simply, I think. Recall that if $f = g$ $P$-almost surely, then $\mathbb{E}_P[f] = \mathbb{E}_P[g]$ (to handle cases where $f$ may be $\infty$ requires defining the integral correctly - see measure theory texts). Define $g(x)$ to be the function angryavian uses - $\frac{q}{p}$ when $p(x) > 0$, $0$ otherwise. Then this equals whatever you mean by $f = \frac{q(x)}{p(x)}$ except on a set of $p$-mass $0$. Ergo, $\mathbb{E}[f] = \mathbb{E}[g] = \int_{\{x:p(x) > 0\}} q(x)$.